# adding layoutWeightSum in a table row through java

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to show a table row with three columns (`TextView`) but i want to divide the table row in three equal parts.

This is easily possible by setting a layoutWeightSum in TableRow in XML and making layout_weight=1 for all theww `TextView`.

But i adding the table at **run time through java** and not by xml.

All i know is the TableRow.LayoutParameter do not provide any thing for weightSum. How can i do this?

```
TableRow.LayoutParams pmRow = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: isn't any answer helped you??

Comment: my bad, i forgot to check the answer. Thanks chintan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by following code.

```
TableLayout layout = //...findViewbyid
layout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
```

And make width `0dp` to all the children (views) of `TableRow` like below.

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_no1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="hi" />
```

**Note**

Above is XML layout design, but you can create run time code also. Its just for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

I've got you covered, mate!

```
myTableRow.setWeightSum(float weightSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `pmRow.span=int value`

like `pmRow.span=3;`

Answer (score 0):

Create a LinearLayout xml (horizontal) with the three required Items ( TextViews). To add the row item at runtime, inflate the above said layout, and set text values and add it.